# Mule ESB. Get credentials in url form for Basic Auth

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

I need to forward security credentials to the remote service. For this I'm sending authentification to my http endpoint using basic authentification and I write them directly into url like: `http://userName:password@localhost:8081/esb/`. If I transit HTTP Authorization header, everything is ok. But each time I want to pass through credentials in URL form I don't see them in message or payload attributes. They disappear. Can anyone help me to find the right way to pass through credentials to a remote HTTP service secured via Basic Authentication?

Comment: Do you want to extract the incoming credentials from the Authorization header?

Comment: No, I want to extract incoming credentials from string like http://userName:password@localhost:8081/esb/, not from HTTP Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

The URL format that you are talking about what a capability of some browsers.  Early versions of IE for example would take the username and password from the URL and put it in the Authorization header.  I don't know of any browser that still supports this model  (http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/834489/en-us).  Is there a reason you can't use the Authorization header as is standard in Basic Authentication?

Comment: Thx for the answer. Yes, IE doesn't support it. But in this case we are talking about standart linux wget and browsers like Chrome and Firefox. I need to support both cases of Basic Auth, because it's like a secure web proxy and i don't know how it will be called. ESB has to implement all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass credential to remote service using Mule .. Then you can take the following **example**.. 
Here I am trying to post request to a external SOAP webservice which has Http authentication .. username:- username and password is password here:

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"  user="username" password="password" port="8090" path="designation" doc:name="HTTP" method="POST"/>
```

**or alternately we can use  it in url in outbound endpoint**

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  doc:name="HTTP" method="POST" address="http://username:password@localhost:8090/designation"/>
```

Comment: Thx for answer. This construction works well for outbound endpoint. In my case I generate http Authorization header for that. The problem is to get username and password from incoming url, but ESB split url string only on host, port and context path. And credentials passed in URL form before hostname are lost.